# How to automate file downloads, while using chrome emulator (chrome driver) with device apple iPhone 5?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Is it possible to automate file downloads by using chrome emulator with device iPhone 5 using selenium web driver.. like we does in chrome or firefox drivers??

Any help.. much appreciated!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting capabilities to download files to dir worked as expected like in browser firefox and chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you need it for, Browserstack might be an option (https://www.browserstack.com/), you can emulate an iPhone (and most other devices), and it integrates with Selenium well. Effectively, instead of creating a Chrome driver, you create a remote one through Browserstack. An example below:

```
DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
caps.setCapability("browser", "IE");
caps.setCapability("browser_version", "7.0");
caps.setCapability("os", "Windows");
caps.setCapability("os_version", "XP");
caps.setCapability("browserstack.debug", "true");

WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(URL), caps);
driver.get("http://www.google.com");
element.sendKeys("BrowserStack");
element.submit();

System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
driver.quit();
```

And from there you can use selenium as normal. More info on setting it up with Selenium can be found here: https://www.browserstack.com/automate/java